# Calculating limsup and liminf of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I want to check if my understanding of limsup and liminf is correct. I know that a limsup and liminf always exist even for divergent sequences and to find them, I need to find a monotonically decreasing and increasing subsequences which converge to limsup and liminf respectively. But what if a sequence $a_n$ is defined differently for different values of $n$?

To be more specific, suppose I have this sequence:

$$
\begin{equation}
  (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} =
    \begin{cases}
      x_n & n=3k-2\\
      y_n & n=3k\\
      z_n & n=3k-1
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$
with $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_n, y_n$ be alternating sequences.

To find the limsup and liminf of this sequence, is it appropriate to calculate the limits as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for all the subsequences and just say that the largest and lowest limits are limsup and liminf respectively? I hope that this is not too vague, please let me know if I need to provide a concrete example, I wanted to find a general way of solving these types of problems.

Comment: This definition seems problematic. For any $2k+1$ if $x_{2k+1}\neq z_{2k+1}$, this is not well defined. Maybe you should write the indices with $3k+...$?

Comment: Thank you @Keen-ameteur, I'll edit it.

Comment: Just one more question. Did you intend that the sequence $a_n$ only take elements of the form $y_{3k}$ into consideration? Because if so, what matters to your question is only the subsequence $y_{3n}$.

Comment: I edited it again as I realised it didn't include all the elements a1,a2,a3,.... now the sequence only takes the elements in the form above.